# Android List view layout Similar to Google play cell (like square)?

Tags: android, listview, layout

I know how to implement listview custom cell, but I need to custom my listview cell like square, and I have no idea.[image] Please help.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update:

There is a new fork at https://github.com/elliottsj/Cards-UI

---

[Cards-UI](https://github.com/afollestad/Cards-UI) is a library that might help you do that.